# Requested but did not find extension point with identifier

Tags: macos, xbuild

i get this error "Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore" when i open zsh terminal. any solution for this error?

Comment: I get this error when I try to run basic shell commands in mac terminal, e.g. `man`.
I opened "XCode" app and quit it. I still get the error but `man` command works now.
I don't know why it's happening, but opening XCode app might make your terminal usable, at least.
Best solution might be to switch to Linux (joke).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar errors for the first call of `cc` in zsh, I solved it by:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`